# Convert quotient to numerical value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
Product Score
AAA     1/4
ABB     1/2
ACC     1/1
```

What I want to do is converting this score column to be numeric using pandas, "/" here represent a divide calculation
so the output shall be

```
Product Score
AAA     0.25
ABB     0.50
ACC     1.00
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried splitting that string on `/`, then casting both elements in the `list` to integers and dividing them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the format is consistent throughout the column, you could use `str.split` to extract the numerators and denominators, and then do the division:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product': ['AAA', 'ABB', 'ACC'],
                   'Score': ['1/4', '1/2', '1/1']})
s = df['Score'].str.split('/', expand=True).astype(int)
df['Score'] = s[0].div(s[1])
print df
```

Output:

```
  Product  Score
0     AAA   0.25
1     ABB   0.50
2     ACC   1.00
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I might do this with apply rather than eval (especially if I didn't trust the source):

```
import re
def extract_and_divide(s):
    m = re.match(r"(\d+)/(\d+)", s)
    return float(m.groups()[0]) / int(m.groups()[1])

In [11]: df.Score.apply(extract_and_divide)
Out[11]:
0    0.25
1    0.50
2    1.00
Name: Score, dtype: float64
```

*Note: You could catch the error if the entry is not of the correct form.*

Answer (score 0):

```
from __future__ import division
df['score'] = df['score'].apply(eval)
```